# Login registration in Firebase auth using shared Preference

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I created Login/registration Authentication using Firebase, and Fill the Data using shared Preference like Full name and Email address on DashboardActivity.
   but Problem is When User1 Create New account and Login, Data Filled Successfully...
 and user2 create Another New Account and Login again Data Filled Successfully...
 but Problem is when again User1 Login and Go to Dashboard Activity then it shown user2  details

This is My problem

This is My code

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.firebaseemailpasswordexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button registerBtn, loginBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeViews();

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        registerBtn = findViewById(R.id.register);
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login);
    }
}
```

activity_registration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register new account" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Full name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Mobile Number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RegistrationActivity.java

```
package com.example.firebaseemailpasswordexample;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText emailTV, passwordTV,fname1,mobnumber;
    private Button regBtn;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        initializeUI();

        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerNewUser();
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerNewUser() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String email, password,firstname,mobnumber1;
        email = emailTV.getText().toString();
        password = passwordTV.getText().toString();
        firstname=fname1.getText().toString();
        mobnumber1=mobnumber.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("email", email);
        editor.putString("firstname", firstname);
        editor.apply();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        emailTV = findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordTV = findViewById(R.id.password);
        fname1=findViewById(R.id.fname);
        mobnumber=findViewById(R.id.mob);
        regBtn = findViewById(R.id.register);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account login"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example.firebaseemailpasswordexample;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText emailTV, passwordTV;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        initializeUI();

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginUserAccount();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loginUserAccount() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String email, password;
        email = emailTV.getText().toString();
        password = passwordTV.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        emailTV = findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordTV = findViewById(R.id.password);

        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}
```

activity_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="371dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="158dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

DashboardActivity.java

```
package com.example.firebaseemailpasswordexample;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String  Tag="DashboardActivity";



    private TextView textView41,textView51,textView21;
    private Button button1;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        setupFirebaseListener();

        textView41=findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView51=findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView21=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button1=findViewById(R.id.button);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);



        String email = sharedPref.getString("email","");
        String firstname = sharedPref.getString("firstname","");


        textView41.setText(email);
        textView51.setText(firstname);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(Tag,"onClick: attempting to sign out user.");
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            }
        });


    }


    public void setupFirebaseListener(){
        Log.d(Tag,"setupFirebaseListener: Settingup the auth state listener");
        authListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user!=null){
                    Log.d(Tag,"onAuthStateChanged: Signin" +user.getUid());
                }else {
                    Log.d(Tag,"onAuthStateChanged: Sign out");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are allowing multiple users/accounts in a same devices after the user logout or another user login you should clear your preferences

Comment: but how??? Share your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your use case to support multiple users to login the same app you shouldn't store the user information's to `SharedPreferences` instead you can use Firebase.

**Step - 1:** After successful registration use `updateProfile` to update the user information

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setDisplayName(firstname)
                            .build();

                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                }
            }
        });
```

**Step - 2:** After successful login use `FirebaseUser` to retrieve the user information's in `DashboardActivity`

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();

    textView41.setText(email);
    textView51.setText(name);
}
```